# HTML on android device don't show correctly

Tags: android, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

My site on desktop looks great but on android  no.

You can see the image

[image: img2]

and my site URL is http://alkhayatt.com

I use bootstrap 3 and RTL and theme.

My code don't show any error and I don't know why that happen.

I did a lot of try but nothing work , so I change classes and make another div,

bootstrap 3 Arabic good style css .

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: remove android tag this question not belongs to android development

Comment: You can remove margin:0 from .row class for mobile view

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

Adding a 100% width to `body` should do the trick.

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}
```